# SQL Appearing in Compiled DLL Files

Tags: vb.net, winforms, dll

I have discovered that our SQL statements are appearing in our compiled DLL files in our WinForms projects.  What are some good methods of hiding these statements in the DLL files?

Comment: Use parameterized queries instead (stored procedures)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term you are looking for is *obfuscation* and there are several commercial products that will do that, as well as some open source ones.

Bear in mind, that someone determined enough will be able to see the strings. That can be done through de-obfuscation techniques or by examining the strings at run time with a debugger like WinDbg.

Obfuscators should be used to protect intellectual property, at best. They should not be counted on for the security of your application. If you are hard coding credentials in your application, I would instead re-consider where they are getting stored or retrieved from. There is no "one-size" answer for that.

Comment: I see.  So it is any string hard coded into the code and not just SQL statements, correct?

Comment: @Acavier , you cannot hide the sql statements/queries by any mean(AFAIK) but you can hide the connection string in app.config

Comment: @zackraiyan obfuscation tools will typically "encrypt" strings with a static key that's further scrambled in the code, but as I mentioned, is far from an ideal solution.

Comment: And, depending on the database, tools can be available to show current and recent queries in plain text in the database.